# Constructing a Gaussian process on $[0, 1]$ such that the sample paths are $1$-Lipschitz continuous with high probability?

Tags: stochastic-processes, gaussian, continuity

In the paper [1] the authors demonstrate that for a centered Gaussian process $\{X_t\}_{t \in [0, 1]}$, if there is a constant $C > 0$ such that
$$
\mathbb{E}[(X_t - X_s)^2] \leq C~(t- s)^2,
$$
holds for all $t, s \in [0, 1]$, then there is a random constant $C' > 0$ such that the process $t \mapsto X_t$ is $C'$-Lipschitz continuous.

I would like to know what can be said quantitatively about $C'$ and its relation to $C$: for example, is it possible to quantify what $C$ needs to be so as to ensure say $C'$ is less than $1$ with at least 9/10 probability?

The one thing I notice in that paper is they show that the moment generating function $\mathbb{E} \exp(\lambda C')$ is finite for all $\lambda$, so this should help --- however I didn't see an explicit expression for this quantity.

[1] Necessary and sufficient conditions for Hölder continuity of Gaussian processes, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.2215.pdf

Comment: First, you need to take a continuous version of $X$ - which is known to exist here - and not any version. Next, under your assumptions, theorem 1 of [1] only says that for every $\epsilon>0$, the sample paths of $X$ and Hölder continuous with exponent $1-\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Just from layercake you have for $\lambda>0$

$$\infty>E[e^{\lambda C_{X}}]=\lambda\int_{0}^{\infty}P[C_{X}\geq t]e^{\lambda t}dt$$

and so for this integral to converge, at the very least we have $P[C_{X}\geq t]<ce^{-\lambda t}$ for all $t\geq N$ for some large $N$.

But in the proof of "Necessary and sufficient conditions for Hölder continuity of Gaussian processes," or even in Schilling we have the bound $c$ showing up in the bound of the Lp moment

[image]

So

$$c_{Holder}^{1/\alpha}c_{0}\geq E[C_{X}^{\alpha} 1\{C_{X}\geq 1\}]^{1/\alpha}\geq P[C_{X}\geq 1]^{1/\alpha}\Rightarrow cc_{0}^{1/\alpha}\geq   P[C_{X}\geq 1].$$

So if $c\to 0$, we get $P[C_{X}\geq 1]\to 0$.